# Quarkus OIDC Client Grant Configuration

Tags: openid-connect, quarkus

Following the guide https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-client#use-oidcclients and in particular the example

```java
@Path("/clients")
public class OidcClientResource {

    @Inject
    OidcClients clients;

    @GET
    public String getResponse() {
        OidcClientConfig cfg = new OidcClientConfig();
        cfg.setId("myclient");
        cfg.setAuthServerUrl("http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/quarkus/");
        cfg.setClientId("quarkus");
        cfg.getCredentials().setSecret("secret");
        Uni<OidcClient> client = clients.newClient(cfg);
        // use this client to get the token
    }
}
```

it is not specified how to set the `grant_type`. Doing a bit of investigation, the class `OidcClientConfig` has a field `grant` with no getters/setters and the only way to set the grant was to access it directly and set the `Type` enum like

```java
cfg.grant.setType(OidcClientConfig.Grant.Type.CODE)
```

It works, but I wonder if this is just a leftover or if the intended usage is different.

Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PR https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/22860 will help with doing a code such as `cfg.getGrant().setType(OidcClientConfig.Grant.Type.CODE)`, thanks